# Application variables get null after post back asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a strange problem. I'm building an asp.net application using web forms.
before one day everything ran prefect. My Application variables get null values after post back.
I'm attaching the code behind

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string tcompid = Application["nowCompId"].ToString();
            List<CompetitorInTauLuEvent> tauluCompetitorsList = new List<CompetitorInTauLuEvent>();
            foreach (DataRow r in competitorsData.Rows)
                {
                    //init competitior in taulu for each competitor from the table
                    CompetitorInTauLuEvent c = new CompetitorInTauLuEvent(r.ItemArray[0].ToString(), r.ItemArray[2].ToString(), r.ItemArray[3].ToString()
                      , r.ItemArray[4].ToString(), DateTime.Parse(r.ItemArray[5].ToString()), r.ItemArray[8].ToString()
                      , r.ItemArray[9].ToString(), DateTime.Parse(r.ItemArray[10].ToString()), r.ItemArray[11].ToString(),
                      r.ItemArray[12].ToString(), r.ItemArray[13].ToString());
                    tauluCompetitorsList.Add(c);
                }
                Application["TauLuCompetitorList"] = tauluCompetitorsList;
        }
```

What could be the problem? (the same happen if I'm trying to save the data in Session/ViewState variables)

Comment: Can you point out in your code exactly where you are experiencing this ?

Comment: Which application variable is becoming null? are you getting any exception?

Comment: @HarveySpecter is happening on the last line of the code.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh Im getting null reference exception. This is hapenning in every post back